# Why did they erase this character's memory?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the season 2 finale of *Agents of SHIELD*,

> Cal's memory is wiped. He is at peace. No longer angry or willing to kill any SHIELD agents. He (truly) reconciled with his daughter and seems just fine.

Why is that ? He could have been a great asset, or if not so, at least not a source of trouble anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't say he's "at peace". He's just had to kill his wipe, and think about the atrocities he committed for her. He may be putting on a brave face, but I think that sort of trauma would leave deep psychological scars. And he's failed in what he set out to do (putting the family back together). That's literally impossible, by his own doing.

Comment: Also note that he was abused by Jiaying - manipulated, controlled and trapped (physically and emotionally). Abuse like that leaves deep scars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SHIELD chose not to keep him as an asset as his instability.

He was a gifted person sure,

> but his inability to control his urges & rage were always a risk.

Also, though not explicitly stated, the following line:

> Daisy: Thank you for doing that for him.

makes me conclude that after the events of the episode, he would want his memory erased.

This was mainly to get over:

> 1. The pain of having killed his wife.
>  2. His obsession with Daisy.
>  3. Losing all hopes of ever reuniting his family.
>  4. His rage issues.

So all in all, I can see why he would want that.

Comment: The earlier implication (when saying goodbye to Skye) was that Cal had volunteered for the procedure.

Comment: @Omegacron - Yes, that was my conclusion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cal was was aware that he could not live like that anymore and that he needed to change his life, so he volunteered to be treated and plus he had to be because other people around him could not bare his violence and rough behavior.

Comment: What reference do you have for this?